# Django using has_change_permission to determine owner

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I want to restrict other user to change object instance other then owner user.

For that I am using `has_change_permission` admin model function but It is not working.

My model:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name = 'book_author')
    ...
```

In my admin.py

```
class BookAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def has_change_permission(self, request, obj):
        if request.user.is_super_user():
            return True
        elif request.user == obj.author:
            return True
        else:
            return False
        if obj is None:
            return False
```

In my views.py

```
class BookUpdate(generic.UpdateView):
    model = Book
    form_class = BookUpdateForm
    template_name = 'accounts/book_update.html'
    def get_object(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return Book.objects.get(id=self.kwargs.get('id'))
```

In my urls:

```
url(r'^update_book/(?P<id>[\w-]+)/$', views.BookUpdate.as_view(),name='update_book')
```

Now when any one goes to this url pattern can edit book, but I need that only author can edit this book.

Is `has_change_permission` right way to do so, or any other better way ?

Answer (score 1):

This will only work in the Django admin interface. It looks like you're trying to update your `Book` instance in a custom form. You can for example overwrite the `save()` method of your model and check for permission here. See [this part](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/models/#overriding-predefined-model-methods) of the doc.